# Запуск Typescript асинхронных функций по расписанию с отсчетом от заданной даты

Tags: typescript

Подскажите библиотеку на Typescript для запуска асинхронных функций по расписанию с отчетом от заданной даты.

Для примера нужно реализовать, чтобы асинхронные функции запускались по раписанию (для заданных периодов)

```
func1 - {'1m', '1h', '1d'}
func2 - {'1h', '4h', '1d', '1w'}
func3 - {'5m', '15h', '1h', '4h'}
```

Причем отсчет времени шел бы не с даты запуска скрипта, а с заданной даты например '1970-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: На чем должна быть эта библиотека? Как и где вы хотите запускать ваши функции?

Comment: Если правильно понял ваши вопросы то - 1) typescript 2) nodejs